# Grouping data with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table something like this:

```
Lecture_ID | Subject | Section | time_Date

0001       | Maths   |  A      | ....
0002       | Maths   |  B      | ....
0003       | Maths   |  C      | ....
0004       | Maths   |  B      | ....
```

I want that the data should be grouped by section so that when i `echo` out the data, it should be something like this:

```
Section A
time_Date
time_Date

Section B
time_Date
time_Date
...
```

How can i achieve a query to do something like this..All i have is like

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Lecutre_info WHERE Subject="'.$_GET['subject'].'" ORDER BY Section ASC';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

print '<h1>'.$row['Section']
print '<br>'.$row['time_Date'];

}
```

You can imagine that i have the `Section` with every record. How can i group the entries together. Also i dont know how many section there will be beforehand and sections could start from any alphabet and not necessarily 'A'. So e.g. there could be a Science class with 1 section named X. Thanks...

Comment: `$current_Section = ''; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['Section'] != $current_Section){ print '<h1>'.$row['Section'].'</h1>'; $current_Section = $row['Section'];} print '<br>'.$row['time_Date']; }` -> create a variable `$current_Section`, check if row's section is the same, if not echo the section, and set the `$current_Section` to the section.

Answer (score 1):

The following sql will output to what you want:

see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea7f7b/21/0

```
select case when length(section) = 1 then
               concat('Section ',section)
            else substring_index(section, '/', -1)
            end as result
  from (select distinct section
          from tbl
        union all
        select concat(section, '/', dt)
          from tbl
         order by 1) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Often, this type of data transform is done on the application side.  You can get the data into this format.  The challenge is getting the extra rows for section *and* putting two different types in the same column (a datetime and a string).  You can do ti as:

```
select (case when time_date is null then section
             else date_format(time_date, YOURFORMATHERE )
        end)
from ((select section, time_date from lecture_info li) union all
      (select distinct section, NULL)
     ) t
order by section,
         time_date is null desc,
         time_date;
```